# Character forward roll causes reverse rotation with next animation

Tags: animation, nla-editor

I'm creating a forward roll animation for my character, and my problem is that if I put that animation and any other animation after it with a blend, then the character does the reverse rotation during the blend time.
It's because the rotation on X axis goes from 0 to 360° during the animation, so as the next animation starts at 0° the blend does what it is supposed to do by going from 360 to 0°.
Is there a way to tell blender to just rotate to the nearest angle?

Thanks